# Clarification on the proof of - Every sequence has increasing/decreasing subsequence?

Tags: real-analysis

**Theorem :** Given any sequence either there will exist a subsequence which is increasing or there will exist a subsequence which is decreasing (and possibly both)

**Partial Proof:** Given a sequence $x_1 , x_2, x_3, ...$ let the set $C$ of positive integers be given by $C = \{N \in Naturals :$ if $m > N$  then   $x_m < x_N \} $.

If $C$ is not bounded above then there exists $k_1 < k_2 < k_3 < ...$ in $C$. The fact that $k_1 \in C$ ensures that if $m > k_1$ then $x_m < x_{k_1}$. In particular $x_{k_2} < x_{k_1}$. Then the fact that $k_2 \in C$ ensures that if $m > {k_2}$ then $x_m < x_{k_2}$. In particular $x_{k_3} < x_{k_2}$. Continuing this way we can see that $x_{k_1} > x_{k_2} > x_{k_3} > .....$ and we have found a decreasing subsequence.

**Questions:**

1. I do not understand what the set $C$ means? Which positive integers is the author pointing at?
2. I am also not able to follow the argument which shows the existence of a decreasing subsequence?

Comment: The sequence of nothing but $1$'s has neither increasing nor decreasing subsequences.

Comment: @John You could also say that the sequence you mention is increasing and decreasing, but is not strictly increasing and not strictly decreasing. Matter of taste I think. E.g. Proofwiki and Wolfram disagree on this.

Comment: @John Many authors define "increasing" and "decreasing" nonstrictly. I presume that is the case here.

Comment: Thanks for the context.  Learned something new today!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $C$ consists of the indices of all the elements that are greater than all the later elements.  You should read the definition carefully to understand this.  If the sequence is $1,10,2,8,3,7,6,5,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,\ldots$ then $C=\{2,4,6,7,8\}$ because the $10, 8, 7 ,6,5$ are greater than anything that follows and everything else is at least tied.  If we change it to $1,10,2,8,3,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3,\ldots$ the new $C$ is $\{2,4,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,\ldots \}$.  By the construction, if we take the elements corresponding to the numbers in $C$, we will have a decreasing sequence.  In the second example, where $C$ is unbounded, the decreasing sequence is $10,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3,\ldots$  Presumably the argument defines another set where the final inequality is $x_m \gt x_N$.  If that set is unbounded, it will give us an infinite increasing sequence.  Now we have to make an argument in case both sets are bounded.

Answer (score 0):

call the sequence $S=\{x_n\}$

if any value $a$ is repeated an infinite number of times then we can derive a weakly increasing sequence consisting of the $x_n$ satisfying $x_n=a$

if the sequence is unbounded then a monotonic subsequence can be selected using the set $C$ defined in the question.

so we need only consider bounded sequences in which each value occurs only once.

by a Heine-Borel argument the set of values taken by the sequence must have at least one limit point, say $b$. if any $x_n=b$ then remove it from consideration. now consider the sequence $S'=\{\frac1{x_n-b}\}$. This is unbounded so we may select a monotonic subsequence $S''=\{\frac1{x_{n_j}-b}\}$.
now $\{x_{n_j}\}$ is a monotonic subsequence of S.